# Docker-compose merging 2 configs produces wrong type in case of string values

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given 2 config files:

s1.yml

```
services:
  test-api:
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
    image: testreg/test-api:v3
version: '3.7'
```

s2.yml

```
services:
  test-api:
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 75M
version: '3.7'
```

When I try to merge the 2 configs the resultant value for the cpus is without quotes thus I get the "services.test-api.deploy.resources.limits.cpus must be a string" error on deploy.

```
docker-compose -f .\s1.yml -f .\s2.yml config

services:
  test-api:
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 0.5
          memory: 75M
    image: testreg/test-api:v3
version: '3.7'
```

From what I can see the value from version keeps the quoted string value, so why is this different for cpus and how can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your docker-compose version is 1.27.x or above.

If you downgrade your docker-compose to 1.26.x it should works.

As a workaround you can keep your current version and use :

`docker-compose config|sed -E "s/cpus: ([0-9\\.]+)/cpus: '\\1'/"`

Comment: what is different between cpus and version fields ? From what I see both fields accept string values, so I expected the same behaviour for both